# Yii2 migration General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: yii2, database-migration

I created my tables like this:

```
$this->createTable('evenement', [
        'id' => $this->integer(),
        'description' => $this->string(),
        'status' => $this->smallInteger()->defaultValue(10),
        'start_datetime' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'end_datetime' => $this->integer()->notNull()
        'created_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'updated_at' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        'created_by' => $this->integer(),
        'updated_by' => $this->integer(),
        ], $tableOptions);
  $this->createTable('event_participant', [
        'event_id' => $this->integer(),
        'user_id' => $this->integer(),
        'status' => $this->smallInteger()->defaultValue(10),
        ], $tableOptions);
    $this->addPrimaryKey('pk-event_participant', 'event_participant', ['event_id', 'user_id']);
    $this->addForeignKey('fk-user_id-event_participant', 'event_participant', 'user_id', 'user', 'id', 'no action');
    $this->addForeignKey('fk-event_id-event_participant', 'event_participant', 'event_id', 'evenement', 'id', 'CASCADE');
```

But I getting this error and I do not know why? What am I doing wrong?

> ```
> add foreign key fk-event_id-event_participant: event_participant (event_id) references evenement (id) ...Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
> The SQL being executed was: ALTER TABLE `event_participant` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk-event_id-event_participant` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `evenement` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE'
> ```

Comment: What **exact** error do you get? What is the schema of related table?

Comment: add the complete `exception` from the console that you are receiving

Comment: the error is "General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign key can be linked only to primary or unique key.

Add PK or UK definition to `evenement` table

```
'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
```

or

```
'id' => $this->integer()->notNull()->unique(),
```